# Spring AOP Custom annotation not firing for my controller

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop

The annotation seems to have no affect. Added more text here to satisfy the editor that this site has requiring a certain amount of verbosity.

My Pom entry

```
<dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

In applicationContext.xml (where other beans are defined)

```
<bean id="myAspect" class="com.myapp.MyAspect" lazy-init="false"/>
```

My aspect

```
 package com.myapp;
    import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    @Aspect
    @Component
    public class MyAspect {
        @Around("@annotation(LogArguments)")
        public Object logArguments(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
            System.err.println("put breakpoint here, never stops here");
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        }
    }
```

The annotation

```
package com.myapp;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LogArguments {
}
```

THIS CODE IS INSIDE OF MY CONTROLLER

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @LogArguments
    public @ResponseBody SearchResult performSearch(@RequestBody SearchForm 
    searchForm, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    LOG.debug("If I put a break point here it stops here, but not in the aspects code:" + searchForm);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Changes to Aspect

- Remove @Component annotation
- Modify the `@Around` annotation and the `logArguments` method signature to make it work. The below example should work,

  ```
  @Aspect
  public class MyAspect {

      @Around("@annotation(annotation) || @within(annotation)")
      public Object logArguments(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,
          LogArguments annotation) throws Throwable {
          System.out.println("put breakpoint here, never stops here");

          return joinPoint.proceed();
      }
  }
  ```

#### Changes to applicationContext.xml

- Make sure to add `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />`
- I don't think you need to specify `lazy-init`

  ```
  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

  <bean id="myAspect" class="com.myapp.MyAspect"/>
  ```

Comment: So added that, now looks like 

`    @Around("@annotation(annotation) || @within(annotation)") public Object logArguments(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, LogArguments annotation) throws Throwable {...`


still does not stop in method

Comment: Could not figure out the darn syntax for adding code, sorry, anyway did what you recommended, didnt work.

Comment: @WarrenGoldman Updated my posting. Please see the changes to `applicationContext.xml` and also removed the `@Component` annotation. I tested the Aspect class with Java configuration and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure both the location you are defining the annotation in is component scanned and that the location you are using it in is component scanned?

Also, I'm not sure if this matters; but I've generally seen people/examples put full package qualifiers  in @around (on LogArguments in this case).

Comment: the annotation is not in component scan, does it need to be?

Comment: the place I am using it is scanned

Comment: Ah, okay; I guess that's not the issue in your case then.  I don't generally add a new annotation, but I cross-cut logging on controller methods like this: @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)").  Don't have a good annotation based example to test quick, sorry.